# How to make a page that Filters data on multiple conditions based on user input

Tags: reactjs

The idea was to create an advanced search page that would enable users to filter data as per their choice by selecting as many as five options to narrow down their search. The results would then later get displayed on a table. Having said that, a user may decide to filter by either using only a single option i.e By state, or by taking multiple options i.e By Name, By District, and By Category or as said earlier up to 5 options. However, I have no way of figuring out how this can be done. You would find screenshots followed by the code below:

A scenario where the user chooses to filter using the By State option

[image]

Scenario, where the options are chosen are multiple to narrow down the search

[image]

The code is as follows:

```
    const AdvanceFilterScreen = () => {
    const [byNameFilter, setByNameFilter] = useState(false);
    const [name, setName] = useState('');

    const [byDateFilter, setByDateFilter] = useState(false);

    const [byCategoryFilter, setByCategoryFilter] = useState(false);
    const [category, setCategory] = useState('');

    const [byDistrictFilter, setByDistrictFilter] = useState(false);
    const [district, setDistrict] = useState('');

    const [byStateFilter, setByStateFilter] = useState(false);
    const [status, setStatus] = useState('');

    const [bySerialNumberFilter, setBySerialNumberFilter] = useState(false);
    const [serialNumber, setSerialNumber] = useState('');

    const [byIssueFilter, setbyIssueFilter] = useState(false);

    const [buttonValue, setFilterButtonValue] = useState('');

    //What the following methods do is set the value of setFilterButtonValue to '' so that 
    //the value of the current selected option turns to blank upon de-selecting them
    //On-Click methods that store the values to choiceArray
    const nameFilter = () => {
        setByNameFilter(prev => !prev);
        setFilterButtonValue('');
        setName('')
    }

    const categoryFilter = () => {
        setByCategoryFilter(prev => !prev);
        setFilterButtonValue('');
        setCategory('')
    }

    const districtFilter = () => {
        setByDistrictFilter(prev => !prev);
        setFilterButtonValue('');
        setDistrict('')
    }

    const stateFilter = () => {
        setByStateFilter(prev => !prev);
        setFilterButtonValue('');
        setStatus('')
    }

    const serialNumberFilter = () => {
        setBySerialNumberFilter(prev => !prev);
        setFilterButtonValue('');
        setSerialNumber('')
    }

    return (
        <div className="advanceFilterScreen">
            <div className="navBarFilter">
                <NavBar></NavBar>
            </div>
            <div className="chooseFilters">
                <div className="chooseColumn">
                    <div className="caption">Choose Filters (Upto 5 filters at a time)</div>
                    <div className="filterOptions">
                        <div onClick={nameFilter}>
                            <div className={byNameFilter ? "nameSelectedFilter" : "byNameFilter"}>By Name</div>
                        </div>

                        <div onClick={() => setByDateFilter(prev => !prev)}>
                            <div className={byDateFilter ? "dateSelectedFilter" : "byDateFilter"}>By Date</div>
                        </div>

                        <div onClick={categoryFilter}>
                            <div className={byCategoryFilter ? "categorySelectedFilter" : "byCategoryFilter"}>By Category</div>
                        </div>

                        <div onClick={districtFilter}>
                            <div className={byDistrictFilter ? "districtSelectedFilter" : "byDistrictFilter"}>By District</div>
                        </div>

                        <div onClick={stateFilter}>
                            <div className={byStateFilter ? "stateSelectedFilter" : "byStatesFilter"}>By States</div>
                        </div>

                        <div onClick={serialNumberFilter}>
                            <div className={bySerialNumberFilter ? "serialNumberSelectedFilter" : "bySerialNumberFilter"}>By Serial Number</div>
                        </div>

                        <div onClick={() => setbyIssueFilter(prev => !prev)}>
                            <div className={byIssueFilter ? "issueSelectedFilter" : "byIssueFilter"}>By Issue</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className={(byNameFilter || byDateFilter || byCategoryFilter || byDistrictFilter || byStateFilter || bySerialNumberFilter || byIssueFilter) ? "filterDropdowns" : "noFilter"}>
                <div className="filterClass">
                    {byNameFilter ? <div style={{ marginRight: "15px" }}>
                        <NameFilter setName={setName}></NameFilter>
                    </div> : null}
                    {byDateFilter ? <div style={{ marginRight: "15px" }}>Search By Date</div> : null}
                    {byCategoryFilter ? <div style={{ marginRight: "15px" }}>
                        <CategoryFilter setCategory={setCategory}></CategoryFilter>
                    </div> : null}
                    {byDistrictFilter ? <div style={{ marginRight: "15px" }}>
                        <DistrictFilter setDistrict={setDistrict}></DistrictFilter>
                    </div> : null}
                    {byStateFilter ? <div style={{ marginRight: "15px" }}>
                        <StatusFilter setStatus={setStatus}></StatusFilter>
                    </div> : null}
                    {bySerialNumberFilter ? <div style={{ marginRight: "15px" }}>
                        <SerialNumberFilter setSerialNumber={setSerialNumber}></SerialNumberFilter>
                    </div> : null}
                    {byIssueFilter ? <div>Search By Issue</div> : null}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <FilterSearchButton name={name} category={category} district={district} status={status} serialNumber={serialNumber} setFilterButtonValue={setFilterButtonValue}></FilterSearchButton>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style={{ marginTop: "50px" }}>
                {district ? <DistrictTable district={district}></DistrictTable> : null}
                <Table buttonValue={buttonValue}></Table>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default AdvanceFilterScreen;
```

`FilterSearchButton` component
This is where the filtering occurs using the props received from the selected options. Right now, this component is configured only to filter using one prop value (i.e either using the name, category, district props etc.). What should I do to filter using multiple conditions using? Just to remind you again, the selected options have been passed on as props to this component.

```
    const FilterSearchButton = ({ name, category, district, status, serialNumber, setFilterButtonValue }) => {
    const [multiFilter, setMultiFilter] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setMultiFilter(dummyData.flatMap(value => value.ward_no.flatMap(
            valueArray => ['grievances', 'general', 'urgent', 'services'].flatMap(
                value => valueArray[value]))).filter(value => value.name === name ||
                    value.districtName === district ||
                    value.type === category ||
                    value.status === status ||
                    value.serial_number === serialNumber
                )
        )
    }, [name, category, district, status, serialNumber, setFilterButtonValue]);

    const searchFilter = () => {
        setFilterButtonValue(multiFilter)
    }

    return (
        <div className="searchFilterButton" onClick={searchFilter}>Search</div>
    );
}

export default FilterSearchButton;
```

P.S: `dummyData` is a JSON file on which the filtering occurs. The  `['grievances', 'general', 'urgent', 'services']` represents the keys over which the filtering occurs. An extract of the JSON data is below. I have removed most of the properties to keep them short.

```
[
    {
        "district": "Kolkata",
        "ward_no": [
            {
                "ward": "6",
                "grievance": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0001",
                        "name" : "Mr.A"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0002",
                        "name" : "Mr.B"
                    }
                ],
                "general": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0003",
                        "name" : "Mr.C"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0004",
                        "name" : "Mr.D"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ward": "7",
                "grievance": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0005",
                        "name" : "Mr.E"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0006",
                        "name" : "Mr.F"
                    }
                ],
                "general": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0007",
                        "name" : "Mr.G"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0008",
                        "name" : "Mr.H"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "district": "Hooghly",
        "ward_no": [
            {
                "ward": "8",
                "grievance": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0009",
                        "name" : "Mr.I"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0010",
                        "name" : "Mr.J"
                    }
                ],
                "general": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0011",
                        "name" : "Mr.K"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0012",
                        "name" : "Mr.L"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ward": "9",
                "grievance": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0013",
                        "name" : "Mr.M"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0014",
                        "name" : "Mr.N"
                    }
                ],
                "general": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0015",
                        "name" : "Mr.O"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0018",
                        "name" : "Bruno Fernandes"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: I don't understand the `flatMap` cascade. Is this really necessairy?

Comment: @Martin If you take a look at the JSON data, you'll see a key named ward_no that has a property of type array which has the following keys ['grievances', 'general', 'urgent', 'services']. So I thought of using the flatMap method to access the properties of these keys by searching deep down one level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might have a performance impact if your list is really big, but since `.filter()` returns back an array, why not chain 5 filters together.

For example,

```
let a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
console.log(a.filter(b => b > 0).filter(c => c > 1).filter(d => d > 2).filter(e => e > 3))
```

This would print the array - `[4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

Wrap you filter logic in a `useEffect` and so whenever an input changes for the props, the useEffect can run again. Maybe you could improve it by using `useCallback` as well.

I hope you get the idea and can use it for your solution

Comment: If the user selected three options to filter with or two for that matter, would this still work? I wouldn't know the number of options selected by the user so the code has to be designed in a way that it accepts any number of inputs at any given time.

Comment: You mentioned that there will upto 5 options. I am assuming these 5 filters are being sent down to your component as props. So, if any prop changes in the parent, the child will re-render and the `useEffect` will run, which in turn will cause the array to filter again. If you could provide a codesandbox of your code, I could take a better look at it. But in theory, yes it should work with any number of filters selected.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-pare-7d109

Comment: You would find the above component in the following path widgets -> button -> filter_search. The path for the component from which the props are being passed is in screens -> advance_filter. I did try implementing what you suggested but don't think I did it in the right way. Would be really helpful if you could rectify that

Comment: Brother, I thought you said you were going to take a look at my code. Would be really helpful if you could tell me how exactly I need to implement what you said? To be honest, I'm a bit of an amateur.

Comment: Hey sorry I am a bit busy, took a look at it but your code seems all over the place. There's no data being rendered in the <Table/> component. Could you clean it up a bit so it has a logical flow, show some data in the table which you expect to be filtered. None of your onClick handlers are working, the filter dropdowns are empty so its tough to understand what data exactly needs to be filtered.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-voice-3jroz

Comment: I'm sorry I somehow posted an old link. This here is the one that works just fine and renders data on the table. Do let me know if you need me to make other changes. The path remains the same and just to save your time, you can directly click on the Advanced Search option on the Nav Bar to take you there. Do keep in mind that the By Date and By Issue filters don't have any functions associated with them so do save yourself the trouble of having to test with those.

Comment: Please check this sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-benz-oqr5w?file=/src/widgets/button/filter_search/filter_search.jsx:0-1299

It will be filtering as exact match. So if you type Siddhartha, it won't show anything, but if you type `Siddhartha Chatterjee`, it will show it.

Answer (score 2):

try to do a filter that you will add to him more  arguments when you start to select more stuff

and then you send it  a method that will do something like that

```
const filterHandler =(data)=>{
  let flag = true;
  if(bySerialNumberFilter){
    flag = data?.ward_no[0]?.grievance?.serial_number  === serialNumber
  }
  return flag;
}
```

in the data you pass the value from the filter and like this you do if to each of the values that the byState is true then you compare it
like that you can add more  search on the fly the flag is initial as true because by default you want it to be display you can put it as no but then you need to check if you dont put any  filter on

Answer (score 2):

```js
const [filteredData,setFilteredData] = useState([]) //render this list
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [status,setStatus] = useState('');
const [district, setDistrict] = useState('');
const [status, setStatus] = useState('');

const data=[......]  //original data

const checkInStatus =(obj,value,key)=>{
 const statusList = ['grievances', 'general', 'urgent', 'services'];
 for (let status in statusList){
   if(obj?.[status]?.[key] === value) return true
 }
 return false
}

useEffect(()=>{
//no need to use byname, bycategory etc. Just filter the based on fields that have a value. To remove a filter just set its value to ''.

let filtered = data.filter(e => district ? e.district === district:true ) //return all data if no filter by district

filetered = filtered.filter(e => {
    if(!name) return true;
    if(e[status] === name) return true;
    return checkInStatus(e,name,'name')
   })
},[name,category,district,status])
```

Only some filters are explained. You can use the same logic for the rest of the filters also

For `status` no need to filter the data . While rendering just render only the fields for that status.

```js
filteredData.map(e=> e[status].map(c=>c.name)}) // store status as a state
```